# Ruby unpack array to block

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
settings = [ ['127.0.0.1', 80], ['0.0.0.0', 443] ]
```

How can I do:

```
settings.each do |ip, port|  
    ...
end
```

Instead of:

```
settings.each do |config|  
    ip, port = *config
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example works because Ruby will destructure block arguments. See this [*archived* article](https://web.archive.org/web/20180721153439/http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html) for more information on destructuring in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is [`Array#map`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ruby-array-map-function/)

```
settings = [ ['127.0.0.1', 80], ['0.0.0.0', 443] ]
settings.map { |ip, port| puts "IP: #{ip} PORT: #{port}"  }
```

which will return

```
#// => IP: 127.0.0.1 PORT: 80<br/>
#// => IP: 0.0.0.0 PORT: 443
```