# Looking at a hash as an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I found this example of using `#any?` on a hash a bit tricky:

"With a Hash, you can use these in two ways. Either with one argument that is a 2 element array of the key-value pair. `candidate[0]` is the key and `candidate[1]` is its value.

```
{:locke => 4, :hugo => 8}.any? { |candidate| candidate[1] > 4 }
```

This returns true because the value of the second candidate `:hugo` is greater than `4`."

Could anyone point me someplace that explains what happened here? I couldn't find a relevant question on SO. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print candidate it will become easy to understand:

```
{:locke => 4, :hugo => 8}.any? { |candidate| puts candidate.to_s } 
# [:locke, 4]
# [:hugo, 8]
```

The `any?` method is treating each key-value pair of the hash as an a two-element array, which means the hash will be treated as an *array of arrays*.

The block passed to `any?` (i.e., `{ |candidate| candidate[1] > 4 }`) returns `true` if any of the the second elements (i.e., 4 and 8) is ever `> 4` and `false` otherwise. `8 > 4`, so the result is `true`.

From the official [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), the `any?` method:

> Passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method
>   returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or
>   nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of { |obj|
>   obj } that will cause any? to return true if at least one of the
>   collection members is not false or nil.

Answer (score 1):

What [`Hash#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-any-3F) does is `yield` arrays of two elements to a given block and return `true` if the evaluation of the block returned something truthy (not `false` or `nil`) and `false` otherwise.

As for why you get two values if you pass a block with two arguments - this is called [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598031/ruby-unpack-array-to-block).

```
def foo
  yield [42, 6 * 9]
end

# only one argument, array is not unpacked
foo { |numbers| p numbers } # prints [42, 54]

# two arguments, the array is being unpacked
foo { |x, y| p x, y }       # prints 42 \n 54
```